# xslt not getting values from namespace elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to retrieve data from elements with a namespace of `dc`. Everything else is working correctly, except for those values.

Here is an abbreviated version of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="sci.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>

<rss version="2.0"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">

<channel>
    <title>SciTimes News</title>
    <link>home.htm</link>

    <description>SciTimes delivers up-to-the-minute news and information on the latest stories from the world of science and technology.</description>

    <dc:language>en-us</dc:language>

    <dc:date>2008-03-24T12:22:54+09:00</dc:date>

    <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>

    <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>

    <sy:updateBase>2000-01-01T12:00+00:00</sy:updateBase>


    <image>
        <title>SciTimes.com</title>
        <link>home.htm</link>
        <url>scitimes.jpg</url>
        <width>620</width>
        <height>96</height>
        <description>SciTimes delivers up-to-the-minute news and information on the latest stories from the world of  science and technology.</description>
    </image>

    <item>
        <title>Visual Memory</title>
        <link>vm.htm</link>
        <description>BOULDER, Colorado - The ability to retain memory about the details of a natural scene is unaffected by the distraction of another activity and this information is retained in "working memory" according to researchers at the University of Colorado School of Medicine. These results reinforce the notion that humans maintain useful information about previous fixations in long-term working memory rather than the limited capacity of visual short-term memory (VSTM).</description>
        <dc:pubDate>Mon, 24 Mar 2008 12:17:37 EST</dc:pubDate>
        <dc:subject>Biology</dc:subject>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

And here's my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1"
version="1.0"
>
<!-- Start base template -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="rss/channel/title" /></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="sci.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="logo">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//image"/>
            </div>
            <div id="datetime"><xsl:value-of select="//dc:date" /></div>
            <div id="links">
                <p><xsl:value-of select="//description" /></p>
                <p><img src="links.jpg" /></p>
            </div>
            <div id="news">
                <h1>RSS News Feed</h1>
                <dc:stylesheet>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//item" /></dc:stylesheet>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<!-- End base template -->

<!-- Start logo template -->
<xsl:template match="//image">
    <a href="{link}"><img src="{url}" alt="{title}" width="{width}" height="{height}" longdesc="{description}" /></a>
</xsl:template>
<!-- End Logo template -->

<!-- Start RSS item template -->
<xsl:template match="//item">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h2>
    <p id="subjtime"><xsl:value-of select="dc:subject" /> / <xsl:value-of select="dc:pubDate" /></p>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="description" /></p>
    <p id="itemlink">[ <a href="{link}">more</a> ]</p>
</xsl:template>
<!-- End RSS item template -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the `<xsl:value-of select="//dc:date" />`, along with `<xsl:value-of select="dc:subject" />` and `<xsl:value-of select="dc:pubDate" />` aren't pulling in the data.

I'm completely new to XML so I'm clearly missing something, I just don't know what. I've searched around looking for a solution, but with no success.

If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a slash at the end of the dc namespace declaration in your XSLT:

```
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1"
```

should be:

```
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
```

Namespace URIs have to match exactly.  Once that's fixed, the XSLT should successfully retrieve the values you want to access.